# Membership equivalent of "if and only if"

Tags: phrase-requests

Is there a phrase similar to "if and only if" for quantities?

Something equivalent to this:

"This procedure will generate one of these, and only one of these."

Comment: "... will generate one and only one of these ...".  Or "... will generate exactly one of these ...".

Comment: "all and only" .

Comment: "one and no more" or "one and no more than one".

Comment: "generate only a single (unit of) ...."

Comment: "This procedure will generate exactly one of these"

Answer (score 3):

"exactly", as in "This procedure will generate exactly one of these."

Comment: See comment above: << "This procedure will generate exactly one of these" – 
Randy Randerson  2018 >> The contributor probably felt that this was too basic an answer to the question for ELU.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Comments aren't supposed to answer the question on Stack Exchange, so I believe that it's accepted (and even encouraged) to turn other people's comments into real answers if they answer the question.

Comment: It's common courtesy to at least mention the one giving the original answer, and best practice is to 'promote' an answer one thinks reasonable into a 'Community wiki' rather than to piggyback.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some suggestions which are logically equivalent to "if and only if":

- is a necessary and sufficient condition for...
- implies and is inferred by...
- is equivalent to...
- is equal to...
- equates to...
- is materially equivalent to...